# SisyphusJS not working with Angular views

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, angularjs

I am doing localStorage for a form, I found [SisyphusJS](https://github.com/simsalabim/sisyphus), it does pretty much everything I want to do. When I tried it on a pages, `form.html` which is loaded via `ngView` (standard angular routing), it does not work, then I took the same form and placed it directly below  on my default page, `index.html`, it worked fine..

What could cause SisyphusJS not to pick up any forms loaded via ngView??

Not working if HTML page is loaded via `ngView`: `views/form.html`

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" name="myForm">
    <input type="text" placeholder="" name="field2" id="field2">
    <input type="text" placeholder="" name="field3" id="field3">
    <input type="submit" value="Sabhmitha">
  </form>
```

Working if HTML page is not loaded via `ngView`:

**HTML:**

```
<head>
 <script src="../public/assets/js/angular/angular-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../public/assets/js/angular/angular-route-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../public/assets/js/angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js"></script>

  <script src="../public/assets/js/angular/custom/app.js"></script>
  <script src="../public/assets/js/angular/custom/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="../public/assets/js/angular/custom/services.js"></script>
  <script src="../public/assets/js/angular/custom/directives.js"></script>

  <script src="../public/assets/js/jquery/jquery-1.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../public/assets/js/sisyphus.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../public/assets/js/jquery/custom/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <form id="myForm" method="post" name="myForm">
    <input type="text" placeholder="" name="field2" id="field2">
    <input type="text" placeholder="" name="field3" id="field3">
    <input type="submit" value="Sabhmitha">
  </form>

  ....
</body>
```

**SCRIPT:**
Looks at the form tag and stores user input to local storage and retrieves the information when page is reopened if the page was closed before user submits the form

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('form').sisyphus();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely that

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('form').sisyphus();
});
```

is run before ngView load and/or DOM is ready for Sisyphus, you can try and run it from controller for that ngView